# Continous Login with Angular and JWT Token

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am getting Access Token and Refresh Token from back-end. When JWT Token expires it gives me error "Token is expired" and custom error code "1002". When token expires there is one API for getting new access token using refresh token.

Suppose, I am calling one API for get user details and for that I received error Token is expired. In that case How can I call the refresh token API to get new access token and again get user details API should be automatically called.

These actions need to be processed at background side. I can handle token expired error at http interceptor. but how to call same api which i have recieved token expired message.

And Suppose if in one page there 2 apis calling and for both of them I received expiration error. Then refresh token api need to be call only once.

Need help on this to implement continuous login feature at Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you store jwt token in frontend and you have an access to get expiration from the token. So you don't need to wait an error from backend.

```
triggerLogout(): void {
    const expiration = this.$jwt.getTokenExpirationDate();
    if (expiration !== null) {
      const timeout = expiration.valueOf() - new Date().valueOf();
      of(null)
        .pipe(delay(timeout))
        .subscribe(() => {
          // token expired 
          // call refresh token api or throw the active user to login
        });
    }
  }
```

Call it in root component's ngOnInit(). Even if you refresh the page it recalculates the expiration and subscribes to it till timout.

If you don't want like it, you can create(or use existing) interceptor to catch UnAuthorized status and call there refresh api